# Command line zip (wamp/windows/php)

Tags: php, command-line, zip

I'm new to php and S.O community.

I'm on :
-Windows
-Wamp

My problem recently is to make a password protected zip for download.
As you know, Ziparchive doesn't allow to make password protected zip, function setpassword is just for decryption.

So I heard I could do that by command line, but to be honest all I understand about `exec()` in command line is that php will execute zip.exe and password protect file.

**So please what's the steps for making this "command line" work in my case (windows/wamp) ?**

Here is my script :

```
<?php
$ZipN='zip.zip';
$Zip = new ZipArchive();
//File path
$file_path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PF/';


function zipFilesAndDownload($ZipN,$Zip,$file_path){
    if ($Zip->open($ZipN, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE )!==TRUE) {
        exit("cannot open <$ZipN>\n");
    }
$Zip->addFromString("testfilephp.txt", "#1 This is a test string added as testfilephp.txt.\n");
$Zip->close();

//Password protect Not working !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
exec("zip -P password $file_path.$ZipN $ZipN");

    //then send the headers to foce download the Zip file
    header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$ZipN");
    header("Content-length: " . filesize($ZipN));
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
    header("Expires: 0"); 
    readfile("$ZipN");

    // Delete the files from the server, even if the user cancels the download
    ignore_user_abort(true);

    unlink($file_path.$ZipN);
    exit;
}

zipFilesAndDownload($ZipN,$Zip,$file_path);
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

7-zip has an amazing command-line based zip utility that supports passwords (`-p` switch). Get it [here](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) (get the Extra version for the standalone commandline). [Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples) are some examples of its command-line usage.

Comment: As it my first time to use command line, all I have to do is download the 7-zip.exe put it in my wamp path, and let the same script ?

Comment: Not the exact same script. You will have to make some tweaks. The examples that I linked include an example of creating password-protected zip archives using the executable. And make sure to copy over the DLLs, too.

Comment: I puted all files in my path, replace line 16 with this  : exec("7za a $file_path.$ZipN $file_path.'testfile.txt'");  but it's not working

Comment: Add a `-pPASSWORD` to the end of that command, replacing PASSWORD with your zip file password.

Comment: New line exec("7za a $file_path.$ZipN $file_path.'testfile.txt' -pPASSWORD");

Comment: I noticed that an empty zip called .zip.zip was created in my path

Comment: Try printing the exec string before running the command so that I can see exactly what command is being run.